# Nunit 3.2.1 failing only when using console runner

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I'm developing framework using c# and selenium. When I am using ReSharper to run my tests everything is working fine.

TCSA = TestCaseSource artibute

But I have strange problem with Nunit 3.2.1 console runner. I have 5 tests and each of them is using one of two TCSA. When I had about 3 tests everything was running fine. But when I add some more then Im getting error on that situation:

When 1st test finish with all TCSA, then 2nd test starts. On second TCSA of 2nd test, Nunit is failing before starting test with another TCSA:

```
1) Error : 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Server stack trace: 
   w System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   w System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   w System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   w System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   w System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activatio
nAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   w System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationA
ttributes, Evidence securityInfo)
   w System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationA
ttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   w System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] ac
tivationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   w System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] ac
tivationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   w NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.Run(ITestEventListener listener, String filter)
   w NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
   w System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   w System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   w System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   w System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   w NUnit.Engine.ITestEngineRunner.Run(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
   w NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)

Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Failed
  Test Count: 0, Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2016-05-19 08:26:28Z
    End time: 2016-05-19 08:32:11Z
    Duration: 343,116 seconds
```

Does anyone know what is the source of this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately NUnit is not showing the the nested exception that actually causes this Reflection error. I'll file an issue on that. Can you get an internal trace using the --trace option?

Comment: Another option for determining what is wrong is to run with the --inprocess command line and see if you get a more helpful error.

Comment: @RobProuse Interesting.. when I placed --inprocess then all test passed.

Comment: The trace may give more info.

Comment: @Charlie in: --trace=LEVEL, which LEVEL will be best?

Comment: To see more info about the error, Error would be OK. But you may need to use Debug latter on to get more info.